# How to export a Report with large amount of records

Tags: reporting, data-loader, custom-report-type, workbench

I have a report of custom report type in unlimited edition with 3000 records, When I try to export,customize or run the report. The data is not showing up. It is giving the message like the report is taking long.
This report is created using custom report type as the base with three objects having relationships.
Is there a way to extract the report data from this report using dataloader, workbench?

Please let me know your thought!..

Thank you,
Prasanth

Comment: 3000 records is not so much strange, i downloaded reports with much larger data. Maybe has some issues your sfdc instance. Anyway, you may export the data via dataloader or workbench. You just need to built the query following the logic of the report.

Comment: Do you have issues with a subset?

Comment: HI klod_Tema,
This report is created based on three objects which I wonder how to bring it on query  with the condition.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a lot of records, but regardless, here is one solution.

Depending on your report, one option would be to use the Data Loader which I believe can export up to 50,000,000 records.

> Setup > Data Management > Data Loader

You can then enter your query as below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jones,
Since the report is a custom report type , it is taking fields from different objects and I find it difficult to bring that in query.

Comment: This is the exact message I'm getting "The query for the preview is taking too long. Consider adding filters to narrow your results."

Comment: @prasanthcheenu Then you'd need to add more filters to reduce the number of query rows. Sometimes this can be done by reducing the date. For example, if you're looking at the Current Year, look at the current Quarter and export 4 of those then just merge the spreadsheets. If you absolutely must have an export of everything in 1 file, you may need to look at writing a little SOQL query that gets whats in your report.